# One word for the "feeling one has after acquiring the habit of being flattered" (भाव खाना)

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

There is a teacher in our school who never approves something unless she is buttered up or flattered. I want to know if there is any word that describes the feeling one has after being flattered.

I am looking for an apt translation of the Hindi *bhaw khana* (भाव खाना).

Comment: What words have you considered but discarded from your associated research about this? Which ones are close but no cigar?

Comment: I am yet to think of an apt word. Being a non-native English speaker, I know the term in my language Hindi but I haven't found any equivalent so far .

Comment: And what does your Hindi word translate to according to various bilingual dictionaries? After one has been flattered, one feels flattered.

Comment: and what is the hindi word?

Comment: Bhaw khana भाव खाना

Comment: In case it helps understand the question, the word for susceptibility to monetary bribery is *venal*. A corresponding word for emotional bribery would answer the title question (The body of the question is asking to describe the feeling feeling one has receiving flattery, which doesn't seem likely to have an answer other than "flattered" or some synonym of "pleased" and may just be a miscommunication/distortion of the intended question)

Comment: Googling your phrase in Hindi presents this: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-English-equivalent-phrase-of-Bhav-khana which makes it sound like condescending, disdainful or pretentious than susceptible or expecting emotional bribery.

Comment: Did you consider *appeased, sated, satiated, gratified, satisfied, mollified, placated*?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions sir. It looks like *mollified* is the word I have been looking for.

Comment: I think the title as an extra level of abstraction which probably is not what you meant.  From the title after being flattered as become so standard as to be labeled habitual,  the person is likely feeling  ***conceited*** or ***pompous***

Comment: and haughty!  high and mighty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may get **a swollen-head**. (informal)

> If someone has [**a swollen head**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/swollen-head), that person thinks they are more intelligent and more important than they really are:

From the web:

- "Don't compliment him any more, or **he'll get a swollen head**."
- "China has become **swollen-headed** because the US has obligations to it that add up to $13 billion."
- "Don't give her any more compliments; **her head is going to swell.**"
- "He really has **a swollen head** after he won the singing competition."
- "I wouldn't want you **to get a swollen head** by telling you that you're gorgeous."
- "He **got a swollen head** since he won a prize for his poetry."

Answer (score 1):

[Bhaw-khana](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-English-equivalent-phrase-of-Bhav-khana)

As I understand it, based on what I read on a popular discussion forum, the English equivalent would be [stuck-up](https://archive.org/details/englishidioms00dixouoft), meaning proud or conceited. I remember hearing **stuck-up** used fairly often among American friends who would kid one another about not being 'friendly enough'.

> Yeah, I know how it is. You bought that new truck, and now you're too **stuck-up** to talk to us regular folks.

This reminds me of an old folk tale, about [Brother Rabbit](https://books.google.com/books?id=yypuIwAACAAJ&dq=stuck-up&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMv7On1bDZAhUX9WMKHWN5BcwQ6AEIMTAB) (aka "Brer" Rabbit). The Fox wanted to trick Brother Rabbit, so he made a humanoid figure made of tar (which is very sticky stuff indeed), and called it Tar-Baby. Brother Rabbit, being a very gregarious sort of fellow, greeted Tar-Baby in passing, and felt insulted when the life-like doll didn't respond.

So he cajoled and teased a little bit (also tried some flattery), in an effort to illicit a friendly response. He asked Tar-Baby, "Why are you so stuck-up? I said hello, and you just sit there dumbly, like you're too good to talk to me."

Anyway, Brother Rabbit didn't realize Tar-Baby wasn't alive, so he got really mad after awhile. Finally, he lost his temper and reached out and swatted Tar-Baby. Well, long story short: he got himself all stuck up -- with Tar-Baby.

Then of course, that's about the time Fox came along and found him like that.

I also ran across this humorous book, *The Natural History of "Stuck-Up" People*, c 1847, whose author describes [stuck-up](https://books.google.com/books?id=LmZQAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=stuck-up&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii-tm92LDZAhVLwGMKHagCBKIQ6AEIQjAE#v=onepage&q&f=false) people as ***purse-proud*** (*p. vi*), which fits rather well with the way that some native Hindi speakers translate **bhaw-khana** as ***pricey***.